# How to add background image and let it under UITableViewCell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

This time the image of background still doesn't fit the scene,this is part of the code `friendListCell` is the`@IBOutlet` of the tableViewCell in this scene :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let BackGroundImage:UIImageView = UIImageView(frame: self.friendListCell.bounds)//UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.width , self.view.frame.height))
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "regularLogin.jpg")!

    BackGroundImage.image = image


    friendListCell.backgroundView = BackGroundImage

          fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]



}


override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

    switch(segue.identifier)
    {
        case .Some("functionSegue"):
            let functionViewController = segue.destinationViewController as! FunctionsViewController
            functionViewController.client = client!
    default:
        super.prepareForSegue(segue, sender: sender)
    }



}

//let AppConfig = TransmissionAgreement(first:"first")
var username:String?
var password:String?
var client:TCPClient?
let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Friend")
let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)
var result:[AnyObject]?
var managedObjectContext:NSManagedObjectContext?
@IBOutlet weak var friendListCell: UITableView!
}
```

[image]

Comment: Have you tried setting the contentMode on the background imageview to fill the entire frame? BackgroundImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill.

Comment: I'm also wondering about that white part at the bottom of the window. Is that part of the imageview, the tableView or the root view (if you're not using a UITableViewController)? How will it look if you set the backgroundColor of the imageView to some other color than white, just for debugging. You could always try to inspect the view hierarchy by using XCode's "Debug View Hierarchy" functionality to figure out the size and location of all the views.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should set the tableView background image.

Try the following:

```
tableView.backgroundView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "regularLogin.jpg"))
```

Also, if you want the cells to be transparent dont forget to set the cell color.

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

Comment: Thanks! The first line of code works, but the second line of code(code about transparent color) doesn't work. The cell is white.

Comment: You also have to make the cell's backgroundColor transparent. `cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()`

Comment: Thanks! Now the color works. But how to make the image can fit the size of scene automatically ?

Answer (score 2):

First: you shouldn't add the background image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath', which means that it will be set every time a new cell is added. Set it in viewDidLoad instead.

And I would suggest that you calculate the size of the background imageview like this instead:

```
let backGroundImage = UIImageView(frame: self.tableView.bounds)
```

Remove the white background by setting the cell's background color to UIColor.clearColor():

```
cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```